# How to I will write loop for custom post type in this marqup

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a custom post type. But in my marqup I've to keep 2 post in one li. So I don't understand how to I write loop for this same marqup. Check my marqup below and Can any one help me ?

```
<li class="clearfix">
    <div class="attorneys-slider">
        <div class="">
            <div class="single-attornys-slider">
                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/Marisa-San-Filippo.jpg" alt="#">
                <div class="hovertext">
                    <h2>Rolf D. Kruger</h2>
                    <p>Partner</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="attorneys-slider">
        <div class="">
            <div class="single-attornys-slider">
                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/Marisa-San-Filippo.jpg" alt="#">
                <div class="hovertext">
                    <h2>Rolf D. Kruger</h2>
                    <p>Partner</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Do you mean that you want to display 2 posts inside 1 <li> and then move on to the next two posts?

Comment: Yes! Correct move the next two post to another next li

Comment: Then see my answer below.

Comment: Could we connect through skype ? and kindly can you show me

Comment: Urm, sorry no. I've given you the code in my answer. It's really very easy to do the rest from there.

Comment: please do not be stalking me on other websites. If you need further help show us what you've done and where you got to after having tried the code I gave in my answer.

Comment: my issue is not solved still :(

Comment: check it kindly http://prntscr.com/ff3ebb

Comment: So where is the code that I gave you in my answer? I don't see it in that screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This may help you. go through the below code**

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php
        while ( have_posts() ) :
            the_post();
            $i = $wp_query->current_post;
            echo ( 0 == $i % 2 ) ? '<li class="clearfix">' : '';
    ?>

        <div class="attorneys-slider">
    <div class="">
        <div class="single-attornys-slider">
            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/Marisa-San-Filippo.jpg" alt="#">
            <div class="hovertext">
                <h2>Rolf D. Kruger</h2>
                <p>Partner</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <?php
            echo ( $wp_query->post_count == $i || 1 == $i % 2 ) ? '</li>' : '';
        endwhile;
    ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to display posts in batches of posts (it's not clear from your original post) then you'll need to do some manipulation inside the loop. To do so -using your example markup- you'd do something limke this:

```
$oddRow = '<li class="clearfix"><div class="attorneys-slider"><div class=""><div class="single-attornys-slider"><img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/Marisa-San-Filippo.jpg" alt="#"><div class="hovertext"><h2>Rolf D. Kruger</h2><p>Partner</p></div></div></div></div>';

$evenRow = '<div class="attorneys-slider"><div class=""><div class="single-attornys-slider"><img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/Marisa-San-Filippo.jpg" alt="#"><div class="hovertext"><h2>Rolf D. Kruger</h2><p>Partner</p></div></div></div></div></li>';

if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 

        $x++; //counter to determine if odd or even row
        $output = ($x%2 == 0)? $oddRow : $evenRow;
        echo $output
    } // end while
} // end if
```

You'd need to tweak that slightly in order to dynamically display your images and other post related data. However, it should cover the bulk of what you were after and give you a base to work out the rest from.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What isn't working? What errors do you get? What does your code look like? What have you tried? What are you expecting to see, that isn't happening?